# ssl on cloudfare gives "Your connection is not private" on browsers

Tags: ssl, https

I have a website that has this address: 
http://my-website.com

I have a free account at cloudfare and then I enabled ssl with the option *full*.  I then used .htaccess to redirect all the traffic to https://my-website.com

Now when I connect to the website I get a chrome error (same with safari) that "Your connection is not private". Does that mean that I have to buy a ssl certificate? I thought that the free version of cloudfare would give me the https already, no need to buy it. Am I wrong? Can you explain me how it works? I have a mediatemple hosting on it.
Thanks

Comment: If you are seeing that error in the browser, it doesn't mean that there is no SSL certificate, but rather that the browser doesn't trust it.  Find out who the SSL provider is, then check the certificate chain in the browser.

Comment: You are right that Full SSL should make your site HTTPS enabled with a trusted certificate. But it does not seem to work like this for you. Given that Full SSL is used widely it is unlikely that this is an error caused by Cloudflare - it is more likely an error caused by the way you use Cloudflare. Only, it is impossible to see what exactly went wrong based on your current description. Maybe it would help if you provide the exact URL so that one can have a closer look how this site is configured regarding DNS (site must be handled by Cloudflare) and certificate.

Comment: Their support says that it can take up to 24h to issue the certificate. I updated the website 19h ago. I will wait until tomorrow to see if it works. Thanks!